# Select query in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

How the first query is different than second in CodeIgniter? and which one should be used in CodeIgniter?

1.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE email = $email LIMIT 1');
```

2:

```
$query = $this
            ->db
            ->where('email', $email)
            ->limit(1)
            ->get('my_table');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's really no difference.

Enable the [profiler](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html) and you will be able to see the actual queries run.

Active record is easier to use when building a query dynamically, and escapes the parameters automatically. Using `$this->db->query()` you must escape it yourself unless you want to use [query bindings](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html) (see bottom of page).

Some queries are just to complicated to use Active Record efficiently, but not this one. Use whichever method you want, but my vote is for [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: +1, I tend to use active record as the code reads better than raw SQL for me.